# SQLITE DB sort query by string formatted date field

Tags: android, sqlite, date, sql-order-by

I have a SQLITE DB with a string field which contains a date in the following format: "01.01.2012".
What I want is to sort the by this string formatted date in a query.
I tried this without success:

```
SELECT * FROM fahrer, fahrzeuge, nutzungsarten, fahrtenbuch WHERE fahrtenbuch.nutzungsart_id = nutzungsarten._id AND fahrtenbuch.fahrzeuge_id = fahrzeuge._id AND fahrtenbuch.fahrer_id = fahrer._id ORDER BY strftime ('%d.%m.%Y', fahrtenbuch.startdatum)
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: What did you get? An error? Dates out of order?

Comment: No Error. The given Order is not sorted. It is orted by the ID of the entry.

Comment: Use ASC to sort date. SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY Date ASC

Comment: I want to sort by the date in the row "fahrtenbuch.startdatum" which is formatted in this way "dd.mm.YYYY". Not by the creation date of the entry. I thought with "ORDER BY strftime ('%d.%m.%Y', fahrtenbuch.startdatum)" it would be done. But it does not seem so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The values in the `startdatum` column are not in a format that SQLite recognizes, so you cannot use it as a parameter to `strftime`.
(Even if it worked, the result would not be sorted correctly because that date format does not begin with the most significant field, the year.)

You could try to extract the date fields so that the sorting is equivalent with the `yyyy-mm-dd` order:

```
SELECT ...
ORDER BY substr(startdatum, 7, 4),
         substr(startdatum, 4, 2),
         substr(startdatum, 1, 2)
```

But I would recommend to convert the values into [a supported format](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) in the first place.

Comment: CL.: Absolute lifesaver. The sorting by substr() ist working fine. Nevertheless I will take a look to the supported formats. Thank you very much!

Comment: Would I have to do this too for my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40129782/why-is-the-order-by-not-working-in-a-sqlite-query Thanks.