# Order by date (string) with Sqlite, DESCENDING doesnt work

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, sorting

I am trying to order my list of objects by the objects' date, descending. The dates are on this form: dd-MM-yyy. The problem is that 10 is interpreted as lesser than 9. (I guess because 1 is lesser than 9). How can i get around this? Now my order looks like this:

- 9-11-2014
- 8-11-2014
- 7-11-2014
- ....
- 1-11-2014
- 29-11-2014
- 28-11-2014
- ....
- 10-11-2014

While i want it to be like this:

- 29-11-2014
- 28-11-2014
- 27-11-2014
- .....
- 1-11-2014

I've tried these two options without luck:

```
        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_DIARY + " WHERE TreatmentId = " + treatment.getId() + " ORDER BY  " + "substr(DATE,7)||substr(DATE,1,2)||substr(DATE,4,2) DESC";

        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_DIARY + " WHERE TreatmentId = " + treatment.getId() + " ORDER BY  " + "DATE DESC";

        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_DIARY + " WHERE TreatmentId = " + treatment.getId() + " ORDER BY  " + "date(DATE) DESC";
```

The last one sorts it, but not DESCENDING unfortunately...

I've also tried doing like in this thread: [SQLITE DB sort query by string formatted date field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13166445/sqlite-db-sort-query-by-string-formatted-date-field)

It sorts it, but it doesnt sort it DESCENDING.

Comment: I think you have to sort by year first, than month and than day...

Comment: Try to use date() like : String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_DIARY + " WHERE TreatmentId = " + treatment.getId() + " ORDER BY  date(DATE) DESC"

Comment: It works, but i cannot get it to sort descending.